# Fitting an image to Gaussian distribution

Tags: image, matlab, function, image-processing, gaussian

I'm implementing a gaussian PDF to which I've already fitted a histogram (matched)

However with changing the MEAN and SD values, there should be changes in the output image- I don't seem to be getting any.

Can someone please explain in the context of images, how would varying the SD & MEAN affect it? 
- if mean = 30, SD= 10, the image would be lighter(merge bright) compared to mean=30,SD=80 ?

Comment: What function are you using to visualize your image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mean will correspond to the overall average brightness of the image and sd will correspond to the contrast, that is, the difference between the brightest and darkest parts of the image. So if the mean remains the same, as in your example, but sd is increased, then overall average brightness remains the same, but the darkest parts of the image get darker and the brightest parts get brighter, increasing the contrast.